# remove new div after 5 seconds

Tags: jquery

i want to add a div and after 5 seconds remove it.
i tried

```
$("#mainContentTD").prepend("<div style='color: #038a00; padding-bottom:10px;'>Your detailes where sucsesfuly... </div>").delay(5000).remove("this:first-child");
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#divID').remove();
}, 5000);
```

The 5000 (ms) means 5 seconds. You should replace `divID` with your own div/element id.

You can make sure that the div exists first using `length`:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  if ($('#divID').length > 0) {
    $('#divID').remove();
  }
}, 5000)
```

Comment: Its worth noting that the check for the div existence is entirely unnecessary as jQuery will not error when calling $.fn.remove() on an empty jQuery collection.

Answer (score 10):

The [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) method only works with methods that utilize the standard effect queue or a custom queue.

> The `.delay()` method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—`.delay()` is not a replacement for JavaScript's native `setTimeout` function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

I.e., you could either use `setTimeout()`: ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/jbnv2/1/))

```
var $elm = $("<div style='color: #038a00; padding-bottom:10px;'>Your detailes where sucsesfuly... </div>");
$("#mainContentTD").prepend($elm);
setTimeout(function() {
    $elm.remove();
}, 5000);
```

Or, you could use a effect method to remove to element: ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/jbnv2/2/))

```
$("#mainContentTD")
    .prepend("<div style='color: #038a00; padding-bottom:10px;'>Your detailes where sucsesfuly... </div>")
    .children(':first')
    .delay(5000)
    .fadeOut(100);
```

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I should have updated before posting :) However, the first part *may* be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, In my case it worked nicely.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('not-valide').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('valide').style.display = 'none'
}, 5000)
```